# Make element resizable in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, dom-events

I want to make div vertically resizable using Angular 2+.
It should works like this: if user mousedown on resizer element and move cursor up/down and then mouseup - the div should have appropriate height.

```
<div #resizable class="resizable">
  <div class="resizer">RESIZE</div>
</div>



export class AppComponent {
  public resizable: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('resizable') set content(content: ElementRef) {
    if(content) {
      this.resizable = content;
      this.resizable.nativeElement.addEventListener('mousedown', this.resizeMouseDown.bind(this))
      this.resizable.nativeElement.addEventListener('mouseup', this.resizeMouseUp.bind(this))
    }
  }

  public resizeMouseDown() {

  }

  public resizeMouseUp() {
    
  }
}
```

I think it should be done by adding and removing event handlers (mousedown, mouseup, mousemove) in specific situation.
Could anyone help me, please?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-h19bwy?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: check this project https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-resizable-element/demo/

Comment: if you could live with the browser handle for resizing there is a css property which can do that: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you has an .html like

```
<div class="resizable">
hello
  <div class="cell-border-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

The css .cell-border-bottom is

```
.cell-border-bottom {
    bottom: -5px;
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    opacity: .5;
    height: 10px;
    cursor: n-resize;
}
```

As you can see the only condition is that the class .resizable has position:relative,e.g.

```
.resizable {
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid silver
}
```

We can use fromEvent 'rxjs' operator, to check if mousedown. If is mousedown, we check if we are mousedown in the "div cell-border-bottom". if true we use variables to get the current position and use fromEvent mouseup and fromEvent mousemove. Some like

```
  alive:boolean=true;
  rectOld: any;
  origin: any;
  moveSubscription: any;
  div: any;
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    //we subscribe to "mousedown"
    fromEvent(this.document, "mousedown")
      .pipe(
         //don't forget unsubscribe
         takeWhile(()=>this.alive),

        //we are only interesting if the "class" of element is "cell-border-bottom"
        filter((event: MouseEvent) => {
          const classs = (event.target as any).className;
          if (classs && typeof classs === "string") {
            const className = classs.split(" ");
            return className.length > 0
              ? className.indexOf("cell-border-bottom") >= 0
              : false;
          }
          return false;
        })
      )
      .subscribe((event: MouseEvent) => {
        //get the parent
        this.div = (event.target as any).parentElement;

        //store the dimensions of the "parent"
        this.rectOld = this.div.getBoundingClientRect();

        //and the position of the mouse
        this.origin = { x: event.screenX, y: event.screenY };

        //subscribe to "mouseup"
        fromEvent(document, "mouseup")
          .pipe(take(1))   //when happens one time unsubscribe using take(1)
          .subscribe(() => {
            if (this.moveSubscription) {  //if exist "moveSubscription"
              this.moveSubscription.unsubscribe();  //unsubscribe
              this.moveSubscription = undefined;
            }
          });
        
        //if there' no moveSubscription
        if (!this.moveSubscription && this.div) {
          
          //listen "mousemove"
          this.moveSubscription = fromEvent(this.document,"mousemove")
            .subscribe((moveEvent: MouseEvent) => {

              //calculate the heigth according the position of he mouse
              const incrTop = moveEvent.screenY - this.origin.y;
              const heigth = this.rectOld.height + incrTop;

              //give to "parent the height
              //I put a minimum of 10px
              this.div.style.height = (heigth < 10 ? 10 : heigth) + "px";
            });
        }
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.alive=false;
  }
```

You can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-epmqfk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

***updated 2021-04-15***: don't forget unsubscribe!

NOTE: I updated, the variable "onDrag" is not necesary (really is a simplifly code of a large proyect I made some time along): [angular-desktop](https://github.com/EliseoPlunker/angular-desktop)